# Augmented Dickey Fuller test: p-value is a nan

Tags: python, data-analysis, statsmodels

I am trying to predict some time series and would like to check stationarity using the p-value of the augmented Dickey-Fuller test:

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
df = pd.read_csv(path)
adfuller(df['values'])
```

With a working example, the following is printed:

```
ADF: -12.792326588071095 
P-Value: 7.033712977770105e-24    
Number of Lags: 0 
Number of observations: 165
```

The problem is that for some time series the values are 'nan' and I don't know why.

Here is an example:

```
ADF: nan  
P-Value: nan  
Number of Lags: 0  
Number of observations: 165
```

I would like to understand the following:
What does it mean? What is the reason for these results and how can I solve the problem?

This is a part from one DataFrame

```py
df.head()
```

|  | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 35.54 |
| 1 | 2.022 |
| 2 | 1.94 |
| 3 | 0.0 |
| 4 | 34.89 |

```py
df.head().to_csv()
',value\r\n0,35.54\r\n1,2.022\r\n2,1.94\r\n3,0.0\r\n4,34.89\r\n'
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to provide a small dataset in order to reproduce the problem

Comment: Can you include a sample of your dataframe so that we can reproduce your issue? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_csv()` directly into your question - thanks!